# Time of creation of a Github Fork

Tags: git, version-control, github

For doing some research on my Github fork , I need to know the exact time it was created. Anyway to do so?
Maybe some metadata somewhere?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use the [GitHub Repos API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/), it does contain the creation date:

```
  GET /users/:user/repos

    ...
    "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
    "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",   <====
    "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z"
  }
```

More precisely, using [`jq` for JSON filtering](https://stedolan.github.io/jq), to get creation date of my old [GitHub repository `VonC/b2d`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d):

```
VonC@vonc MINGW64 /c/Users/vonc/git
$ curl https://api.github.com/users/VonC/repos | jq '.[] | select(.name=="b2d") | .created_at'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  153k  100  153k    0     0   105k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  105k
"2015-03-28T19:58:35Z"
```

---

Or, using the GitHub CLI [`gh repo view`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_view) (no need for `curl -s https://api.github.com`)

```
gh repo view vonc/b2d --json createdAt --jq ".createdAt"
2015-03-28T19:58:35Z
```

If you still want to use the GitHub Repos API:

```
gh api repos/vonc/b2d --jq ".created_at"
2015-03-28T19:58:35Z
```

Comment: @LeoLee Thank you. I have edited the answer to include an example using `curl` in combination with `jq` (JSON filtering)

Answer (score 2):

The currently correct, most precise and simplest answer is:

```bash
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repository> | jq -r '.created_at'
```

Example:

```bash
> curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/yt-dlp/yt-dlp | jq -r '.created_at'
2020-10-26T04:22:55Z
```

Answer (score -1):

If the first commit of your repository was made not long after the repo itself was created, you could always approximate the creation time of the repo by doing `git log --reverse` and find the authored date of the commit, or if the root commit was never modified, you can pass `git log --reverse --format=fuller` to get the committed date too.

Comment: You don't understand the question, which asks about a **fork** creation date. The method you're describing simply gives the first commit date of a generic git repo, which is obviously not correlated with a fork creation that will evidently always be strictly later, and most often much later.